# Extjs 4. location.hash without explicit ids

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

In my panel I have a navigation tree. On `itemclick` window scrolls down to a particular form field. I do it like this:

```
location.hash = 'UID'
```

So, I can get the element by `Ext.getCmp(UID)`. But I know, that this practice of using ids is not good, because of possible layout crashes. So, I now want to use `itemId` instead of `id`, but the problem is how to simulate the same behaviour as of `location.hash`.

Comment: If they are guaranteed to be unique then there is no issue, perhaps aside from it being somewhat messy architecture.

Comment: The question is how to scroll to this element, if it does not have an id specified. In this case location.hash does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have `container` of the element and the `element` itself then call:

```
element.scrollIntoView(container, ...);
```

See [Element Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-scrollIntoView) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you don't define an ID, this doesn't mean that the element has no ID. ExtJS creates unique IDs automatically.

A good OO design should give the references you need. ExtJS does this in I would say 99.9%.

Example: An **itemclick** event, has a parameter **this**. Which can be the window, panel, button, or whatever.

```
itemclick( myElement, record, item, index, e, eOpts ) {
    ...
    location.hash = myElement.id;
    ...        
}
```

If you have one Ext.Component but you want a parent or child component of this element, you should use **up()** and **down()** method. This is still faster as Ext.getCmp() because you don't need to search the whole DOM.

```
 myButton.up(); //get parent
 myButton.up("toolbar") //tries to find a parent with xtype "toolbar"
 myButton.down("textfield"); //you get it...
```

Comment: Thank you! I know `up` and `down` functions and how to use them. As for your answer, you misunderstood a little bit. I said, that "In my panel I have a navigation tree. On itemclick window scrolls down to a particular form field". But in your code `myElement` corresponds to menu items and so their generic ids may not coincide with `form fields`.

Comment: But I know what you mean. I guess, I should check another possible solution - first of all, to get the form field element by down("#itemId") and then to to use location.hash = element.id, where id is created by ExtJS automatically. If it works, I will mark your answer as a solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I think we are talking from the same thing ;) Listen to an event, query the element you want with down() or up() and use element.id. That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: Thanks! I have no time to check it today, but I'm 100% certain, that it works. So, you did it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the item with the following command:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=' + UID + ']')[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to get an element. The problem, as I said, is how to scroll to this element like location.hash does it